# Is there a significance to the quill/feather when Angry Birds counts your score?

Tags: android, angry-birds

When I play Angry Birds (Android, various versions), and beat a level, it comes up with a screen that calculates a score/shows how many stars you got.

Next to the stars/score I see an image of a quill/feather.

Is that image significant in terms of gameplay?

Or is it simply a decoration on that screen?

[image]

Comment: From what I remember playing the game, it means you didn't use the Eagle or whatever it's called. Not putting as an answer yet because this is just what I think it is, and I don't remember entirely. Give me a few minutes to check

Answer (score 1):

After quickly testing this, I can say 100% that the feather that appears on the score screen indicates if you have used the Eagle in the level. It will also appear in the bottom right corner of the level icon.

Level Select:

[image: Level Select]

Level 1 Scores:

[image: Level 1 Stats]

Note that the level 1 score screenshot was taken AFTER the level select screen shot. So that feather will always show up in full color if you have used the eagle on a level.

Comment: I see. So what I see is a **placeholder** for the real feather? (given that it's not colored like yours and I never ever use an eagle?)

Comment: That's correct. That's all it is is a placeholder, and probably also to assure you you never used it on that level.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expound on this answer a bit.  The feather actually appears when you have achieved, "Total Destruction" on a level with the Mighty Eagle.  After you use the Mighty Eagle and the level is finished the feather will start to fill and your "Eagle Highscore" is shown in the form of a percentage.  If your "Eagle Highscore" reaches 100% you've earned Total Destruction and the feather will now be shown on the level selection button as shown in @LLF's answers.  If you simply use the Mighty Eagle a tuna can will appear on the level selection screen.

Getting Total Destruction with the Mighty Eagle is not always easy.  One tip is to use the normal birds first to weaken the pigs structure.  You can then call in the Mighty Eagle to finish the job.  AngryBirdsNest has a bunch of other great tips in their Mighty Eagle article here: http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-mighty-eagle-explained/.  They also have walkthroughs for all levels if you get stuck.

**Eagle Highscore 60%**

[image]

**Eagle Highscore 100%**

[image: Eagle Highscore 100%]

**Tuna Can (used Mighty Eagle) and Feather (100%)**

[image: Tuna Can (used Mighty Eagle) and Feather (100%)]

Comment: If you mean to expand another answer, I think the best you can do is suggest an edit. Not post a different answer. (Due to the voting system, the best answer rises to the top, so your initial statement might not be true). Welcome to the Arcade!